# Get second level terms of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I want to get second level terms of a specific parent (first-level) term in a custom taxonomy. Sounds complicated but would be useful.

```
Term 1
   SubTerm-1.1
   SubTerm-1.2
       SubTerm-1.2.1
Term 2
   SubTerm-2.1
```

Say, if `SubTerm->parent` is Term 1's id, then i want to output SubTerm 1.1 and 1.2 but not 1.2.1.

`wp_list_categories(array('depth' => 2, 'taxonomy' => 'customtax'));` is not i'm looking for as it lists terms with their links, which i dont want to, and there is no filtering option by `SubTerm->parent` id.

So any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PHP's `array_filter` to process the results of a taxonomy query function that returns its results, and then display them. Something like:

```
# This returns the whole taxonomy...
$whole_tax = get_terms('customtax', array('hide_empty' => 0));
$second_level = array_filter($whole_tax, function ($t) {
  # This term has a parent, but its parent does not.
  return $t->parent != 0 && get_term($t->parent, 'customtax')->parent == 0;
});
```

At this point you can render `$second_level` to output in whatever format you want.

NB. If this is often used on a busy side should avoid all those extra `get_term` calls by reading from the `$whole_tax` array assuming the documentation's statement that `get_term` always hits the database when passed an id.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in this line: $second_level = array_filter($whole_tax, function ($t) {

Comment: @Adige72 What version of PHP are you using? (Inline functions were added in 5.3 I think.)

Comment: Hmm it's 5.2.6. I'll update and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Adige72 You could also defined a named function and pass its name, but the inline function is far more elegant (and adds the ability – via a `use` clause – to pass additional data from the caller): definition isn't separate and no global namespace pollution for a local problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
$tax ='taxonomy';
        $args = array(
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'hide_empty' => false,
          'parent' => 0,
          );
    $toplv_term_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
        foreach($toplv_term_query->get_terms() as $toplv_term){
             $args = array(
               'taxonomy' => $tax,
               'hide_empty' => false,
               'parent' => $toplv_term->term_id,
              );
          $secondlv_term_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
              foreach($secondlv_term_query->get_terms() as $secondlv_term){
                   $secondlv_term->term_id;

             }
        }
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?